# How can I show a YouTube video in-app?

Tags: android, youtube, video-player

In the [Relay for Reddit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=free.reddit.news&hl=en) app, YouTube videos load in-app, like so:

[image: Relay for Reddit in-app YouTube player]

Is this something that is built into Android? Or would I have to create my own custom view in order to support this? If the latter, would it be a VideoView or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **YouTube Android Player API**

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Example :

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

> The YouTube Android Player API enables you to incorporate video
>   playback functionality into your Android applications. The API defines
>   methods for loading and playing YouTube videos (and playlists) and for
>   customizing and controlling the video playback experience.

Here you can find many different samples:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications